# Replace many different strings within a text file using Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, text-editor, replace

I have a text file where I need to replace a lot of different strings of letters with other strings of letters, e.g.

```
AA > b
BB > hes
kg > ret
```

etc.

Naturally, I would like to replace them all at once.  I was wondering how to do this from within a text editor (i.e. not with tools like `sed`).  Is this possible in Notepad++?

Comment: `it might be inappropriate for this site` if you know it does not belong here, why did you post then?

Comment: I've seen multiple questions here regarding search and replace in text editors, because the questions or answers involve things like regular expressions. Since I don't _know_ whether the solution requires regular expressions, I'm not sure whether I should/could ask it here. As stated in the first line of my post.

Comment: @Sverre I edited this to be a clear, well-defined question - If you want a solution for more general editors, or are open to using a unix tool, please edit your post accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notepad++ can not do this and I have never seen any other editor that can.

One option is to write your own Notepad++ plugin for it, if you are in to that sort of thing.

Otherwise command line tools or some kind of script is the easiest option.